# How to convert object literal to function

Tags: javascript-objects, javascript

Is there any dynamic way to convert/clone this object:

```
var object = {
    a: 2,
    b: function(){
         return this.a;
    }
}
```

Into this kind of function object:

```
function object(){};

object.a = 2;
object.b = function(){
    return this.a;
};
```

Is this possible? how can I do so dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

You can just copy everything, though I would use the prototype:

```
function toClass(obj) {
    var func = function () {};
    for(var i in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            func.prototype[i] = obj[i];
        }
    }

    return func;
}
```

A whole other question is how useful this actually is and whether there is a better solution to the underlying problem.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pb8mv/

Comment: Is this a question directed at me? If so, please be more specific. Why would I what?

Comment: +1: Yes, indeed, why would one want to clone the object to a function-object?

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit strange that you need such a thing. If I have to guess, I think that you have an object and you want to extend it. I.e. you want to create function based on that object, so you later create multiple instances of it. That's possible and here it is a little snippet showing how:

```
var object = {
    a: 2,
    b: function(){
         return this.a;
    }
}
var extend = function(obj) {
    return function() {
        return Object.create(obj);
    }
};

var Class1 = extend(object);
var ob1 = Class1();
ob1.a = 10;

var Class2 = extend(object);
var ob2 = Class2();
ob2.a = 23;

console.log(ob1.b(), ob2.b());
```

The result of the script is

```
10 23
```